# Failure To Execute SQL Subquery With Join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

Please can someone tell me what I'm not doing right. Here is a query I want to execute, but nothing happens when I run the command. I'm new to SQL so pardon my mistake, if any.

```
 SELECT  t.*,
 COUNT(DISTINCT t.subjects) AS subjectenrollment,
 u.urefnumber,
 u.uresidence
 FROM 
 (
  SELECT r.*,
  @curRank := IF( @prevRank = finalscore, @curRank, @incRank ) AS position,
  @incRank := @incRank + 1,
  @prevRank = finalscore
  FROM studentsreports r, 
  (
   SELECT @curRank := 0, 
   @prevRank = NULL, 
   @incRank := 1
  ) c
  ORDER BY finalscore ASC
 ) t LEFT JOIN studentstbl u ON t.studref = u.urefnumber
 WHERE t.author = :staff
 AND t.studentname = :student
 AND t.academicyr = :year
 AND t.academicterm = :term
 AND t.program = :program
 AND t.classes = :level
 AND t.subjects = :subject;
```

As it can be seen from the code, I'm trying to fetch students records, and include a column for position in each subject, as well as the number of students offering each subject. More over, I want to include each student's residential status, which is also in a different table.

At a point, I even want to add their accumulated raw scores, that is, the summation of all the marks obtained in each subject, but I don't know how to even make that possible. A friend has already suggestted acheiving that in separate queries, but unfortunately, I could get that well.
Please, I will be very grateful for your help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your use of `COUNT()` in your toplevel query, you're seriously misusing MySQL's nonstandard implementation of `GROUP BY`. `COUNT()` is an aggregating function. Read this.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html Also, try to get some of your information retrieved correctly before you start in on the all the `@rank` stuff. It's tricky and nonstandard. It tries to force a procedural model on top of MySQL's declarative model so it performs in quirky ways.

Comment: Are you running this query in code such as PHP as I see colon-prefixed binded params? Either values in these params together return no result or query throws an error/exception that you are not catching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this adjustment using derived tables and correlated subqueries without need of @variables. SQL statement below handles following needs with the employed stategy listed alongside:

1. Column for position/rank in each subject        - *Aggregate Correlated Count Subquery at Top Level*
2. Number of students offering each subject   - *Aggregate Count Derived Table (Inner Join clause)*
3. Each student's residential status  - *Group By Field (From clause)*
4. Summation of all marks in each subject     - *Aggregate Sum Derived Table (From Clause)*

**SQL** *(with binded params)*

```
SELECT main.student_number, main.subjects, main.student_residence,
       main.accum_raw_scores, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM (SELECT s.studref, s.subjects, SUM(s.finalscore) AS total_score
              FROM studentsreports s
              GROUP BY s.studref, s.subjects) AS sub
        WHERE sub.subjects = main.subjects
        AND sub.total_score >= main.accum_raw_scores) AS subject_rank,
       cnt.subject_student_count
FROM
  (SELECT r.studref AS student_number, r.subjects, u.uresidence AS student_residence, 
          SUM(r.finalscore) AS accum_raw_scores       
   FROM studentreports r
   LEFT JOIN studentstbl u ON r.studref = u.urefnumber
   WHERE r.author = :staff
   AND r.studentname = :student
   AND r.academicyr = :year
   AND r.academicterm = :term
   AND r.program = :program
   AND r.classes = :level
   AND r.subjects = :subject
   GROUP BY r.studref, r.subjects, u.uresidence) main
INNER JOIN 
   (SELECT sub.subjects, COUNT(*) AS subject_student_count 
    FROM studentreports sub 
    GROUP BY sub.subjects) cnt
ON cnt.subjects = main.subjects
```

Comment: @Paefait Thank you so much for such a wonderful support. Infact, I don't know how best I can show my gratitude to you, because words can't describe how appreciative I am to this perfect solution. You have saved me beyound expectation. Man, I wish you all the best of luck life has to offer. Thanks so much. The solution was exact, right on the spot and indeed a perfect one. It deserves 5 stars.

Comment: Wow!!! Without data, I was shooting in the dark. Glad the SQL was right on point. That might have the best reply yet. Glad I could help. Happy coding!

Comment: @Paefait My regards to you! Please i'm having this challenge of adding overall position or rank for every student, using the accumulated marks from the various subjects. Can you please help me out, with regards to the above query you marvelousely assisted me on.